# Receiving the same message twice

Tags: c#, skype, skype4com

Hey i'm building a skypebot and i can't figure out why i'm receiving the message 2x

This is the code im using

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        client = new Skype();
        client.MessageStatus += Client_MessageStatus;
        AttachToSkype();
    }
        private void Client_MessageStatus(ChatMessage pMessage, TChatMessageStatus Status)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(pMessage.Sender.Handle + " Says: " + pMessage.Body);
    }
```

Thanks for your time -Tristan

Comment: I think somehow `MessageStatus` event is being subscribed multiple times. Which shouldn't happen.  Try `unsubscribing` this event after it's work is done.

Comment: What does the "AttachToSkype" function?

Comment: @Jauch it checks if skype is opened and tries to attach

Answer (score 0):

MessageStatus event is called every time message's status has been changed.
You need check for TChatMessageStatus. It should be cmsReceived.

```
private static void Skype_MessageStatus(ChatMessage pMessage, TChatMessageStatus Status)
{
       if (Status != TChatMessageStatus.cmsReceived) return;

       MessageBox.Show(pMessage.Sender.Handle + " Says: " + pMessage.Body);
}
```