# user receiving same message twice from Skype bot

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service, microsoft-skype-bot

I was trying to send skype-bot message to skype-user using [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#conversation-operations) in nodeJs, but user receives bot-message two times of that single message. I am sending the message  with HTTP POST request only single time using a single activityId. Is there any way to control duplicate messages? what can be the reason behind this?

I have gone through this [Receiving the same message twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39058352/receiving-the-same-message-twice)
Can anyone please like to help finding the issue?

*[No sdk or other library is used ]*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue. I was subscribing redis to read message and deliver to user. I found that it was happening twice[one in my app uploaded to server and another in my local machine]. Now resolves.
 Thanks !